# Can't find path to file in assets folder in Capacitor app

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a Capacitor app (Capacitor 4) which uses the Cordova Media plugin to play sound, as there is no equivalent native plugin for Capacitor 4 yet.

I can play sounds from the web via urls, but not from the app's own fixed assets directory, it just says file not found.

I've tried **public/assets/audio/sound.mp3** and **assets/audio/sound.mp3** so far. The latter path works in Cordova apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around this with the pre-release version of the capacitor native audio plug in - @capacitor-community/native-audio@4.0.0-0

Last commit was three months ago.